# enable custom configuration section in service definition csdef, service configuration cscfg in azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-configuration

I am moving my .NET MVC application to Microsoft Azure cloud services. I planning to move configurations from web.config to csdef/cscfg in azure.

My web.config file has few custom configuration sections.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <section name="myConfig1" type="MyNamespace.MyClassType" />
  </configSections>

  <myConfig1 someProperty1="someValue1" someProperty2="someValue2" someProperty3="someValue3">
     <test1 testproperty=testValue />
     <test2 xProperty=xValue />
  </myConfig1>
</configuration>
```

I am using this configurations when application starts(global.asax).
I want to convert this into csdef/cscfg. 
Normally cscfg have key/value pair of configuration settings..

Can anyone suggest me how to convert custom configurtion to service configuration in azure?

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config will still be utilized in an Azure web role.  The csdef file's purpose is to define the environment for your application - things like the VM size and any custom start-up tasks.  You can put any key/value pairs in cscfg files or leave them in your web.config.